Gazebo harmonic on ubuntu 24.04 not rendering despite having latest openGl im using ROS Jazzy
[GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [gz-rendering-ogre2]
libEGL warning: Not allowed to force software rendering when API explicitly selects a hardware device.
libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1301]  Unable to create the rendering window: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): currentGLContext was specified with no current GL context in GLXWindow::create at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/windowing/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 165)
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1309] Unable to create the rendering window after [11] attempts.
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1191] Failed to create dummy render window.
[GUI] [Err] [Ogre2RenderEngine.cc:1192] Please see the troubleshooting page for possible fixes: https://gazebosim.org/docs/fortress/troubleshooting


There are instructions here that solved the issue for me. I would recommend setting the QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb in ~/.bashrc so that you don't need to set it everytime you run gz sim.
